# Date picker in Excel 2013 64bit

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I'm using Excel 2013 64bit, in earlier version excel 2007 I've used Microsoft Date Time control in more tools options., but I could not found the same one or related one on excel 2013.

I've tried all those solutions in microsoft forums, even I can't found any add-on for this.

Has any one the solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know active-x buttons are not supported in Excel 64-bit.

If you want to use active-x buttons such as date picker you need to install Office 32-bit which can also be installed in Windows 64-bit or to create them by yourself.